# Erase, Read And Write in Parallel Nor Flash of STM32F429NI

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f4, flash-memory, stm32cubeide

I am working on the erase, read and write of external nor flash in STM32F429NI. I am using CubeMx to generate the code. When only my nor pins are selected in the .ioc file and when I perform erase, read and write it is working fine. But when I integrate this changes to my whole project which includes internal flash, ethernet etc. The data are not received properly. Also the API's provided by the drivers for nor flash in stm32 is for 16 bit data is there any way to make the data to be written in 8 bits.

BSP of STM32F429NI
https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/STM32CubeF4/blob/master/Drivers/BSP/STM324x9I_EVAL/stm324x9i_eval_nor.c

Pins selected for NOR Flash in CubeIde is:
PD4, PD5, PD6 and PD7.

```c
void MX_FMC_Init(void)
{
  FMC_NORSRAM_TimingTypeDef Timing = {0};

  hnor1.Instance = FMC_NORSRAM_DEVICE;
  hnor1.Extended = FMC_NORSRAM_EXTENDED_DEVICE;
  /* hnor1.Init */
  hnor1.Init.NSBank = FMC_NORSRAM_BANK1;
  hnor1.Init.DataAddressMux = FMC_DATA_ADDRESS_MUX_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.MemoryType = FMC_MEMORY_TYPE_NOR;
  hnor1.Init.MemoryDataWidth = FMC_NORSRAM_MEM_BUS_WIDTH_16;
  hnor1.Init.BurstAccessMode = FMC_BURST_ACCESS_MODE_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignalPolarity = FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_POLARITY_LOW;
  hnor1.Init.WrapMode = FMC_WRAP_MODE_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignalActive = FMC_WAIT_TIMING_BEFORE_WS;
  hnor1.Init.WriteOperation = FMC_WRITE_OPERATION_ENABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WaitSignal = FMC_WAIT_SIGNAL_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.ExtendedMode = FMC_EXTENDED_MODE_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.AsynchronousWait = FMC_ASYNCHRONOUS_WAIT_ENABLE;
  hnor1.Init.WriteBurst = FMC_WRITE_BURST_DISABLE;
  hnor1.Init.ContinuousClock = FMC_CONTINUOUS_CLOCK_SYNC_ONLY;
  hnor1.Init.PageSize = FMC_PAGE_SIZE_NONE;

  Timing.AddressSetupTime = 4;
  Timing.AddressHoldTime = 15;
  Timing.DataSetupTime = 7;
  Timing.BusTurnAroundDuration = 15;
  Timing.CLKDivision = 16;
  Timing.DataLatency = 17;
  Timing.AccessMode = FMC_ACCESS_MODE_A;

  if (HAL_NOR_Init(&hnor1, &Timing, NULL) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler( );
  }

}
```

```c
uint8_t BSP_NOR_WriteData(uint32_t uwStartAddress, uint16_t* pData, uint32_t uwDataSize)
{
  uint32_t index = uwDataSize;
  
  while(index > 0)
  {
    /* Write data to NOR */
    HAL_NOR_Program(&norHandle, (uint32_t *)(NOR_DEVICE_ADDR + uwStartAddress), pData);
    
    /* Read NOR device status */
    if(HAL_NOR_GetStatus(&norHandle, NOR_DEVICE_ADDR, PROGRAM_TIMEOUT) != NOR_SUCCESS)
    {
      return NOR_STATUS_ERROR;
    }
    
    /* Update the counters */
    index--;
    uwStartAddress += 2;
    pData++; 
  }
```

```c
uint8_t BSP_NOR_ReadData(uint32_t uwStartAddress, uint16_t* pData, uint32_t uwDataSize)
{
  if(HAL_NOR_ReadBuffer(&norHandle, NOR_DEVICE_ADDR + uwStartAddress, pData, uwDataSize) != HAL_OK)
  {
    return NOR_STATUS_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    return NOR_STATUS_OK;
  }
}
```

Comment: @0___________ , could you please help me with this.

Comment: `16 bit data is there any way to make the data to be written in 8 bits.` - no it is how FLASH memory work. If you want to write 8 bits you need to add some of your own fancy logic - ie read, mask, OR and write + some additional logic to aggregate the data.

Comment: @0___________ , OK. When I select the pins in the .ioc for external nor flash, there is an overlap of the same pins with the ethernet pins of the F429NI board would this be an issue for read / write of external nor flash. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is the issue.

Comment: @0___________, could you please give me a lead on solving this issue. I need to enable both the Ethernet and the external Nor flash in the CubeMx and achieve the desired result. My address bits for FMC: 26, Data bits: 16, Write enable: 1 bit, Wait : 1 bit.